Confusion on Question from Kenneth Discrete Math Textbook

Suppose there are signs on the doors to two rooms. The sign on the
first door reads “In this room there is a lady, and in the other one
there is a tiger”; and the sign on the second door reads “In one of
these rooms, there is a lady, and in one of them there is a tiger.”
Suppose that you know that one of these signs is true and the other is
false. Behind which door is the lady?

Q.1: Is this question saying there is only 1 lady and 1 tiger in the scenario?
Q.2: Does the sign on the 2nd door give the possibility that the lady and tiger are in same room?

Yes, to Q2. The answer to Q1 is that the question is ambiguous in that regard, but the final question (“the lady”) suggests that yes is the intention.

But how is the main question "Behind which door is the lady " answered ?

@TedShifrin Wait but then how can you answer the question then?

If the sign on the first door is true, then certainly the sign on the second door is also true. This contradicts the given information. Thus, the sign on the first door must be false. Thus, either there is no lady in the first room or there is no tiger in the second. This means that we have one of the scenarios ()(LT), (LT)(), or (T)(L). Because of the ambiguity of the second sentence (since it says "in one room" and "in one room" rather than "in one room" and "in the other room"), we are stuck. The question is ill-posed. Your confusion seems warranted. Did Rosen intend this confusion?

@TedShifrin Ya that's exactly my question lol? Also the textbook forgot to give an answer for it so I'm not sure.

To explicitly answer the stated questions:

Is the question saying there exist only one lady and one tiger in this scenario? By the choice of article "the" at the end of the set-up (i.e. "Behind which of the doors is the lady?"), it seems that the intent is for there to be exactly one lady and (maybe) exactly one tiger. This is a good question!, for the question is ambiguous about this detail otherwise.

Does the sign on the second door leave open the possibility that the lady and tiger are in fact in the same room? I'll turn around and throw the question back at you: What do you suspect? Think on it. This is a central part to the question. (If I were to give a hint: Where in the set-up is it suggested that you can't have both in a single room? Or is there no such suggestion?)



I'd say the answer for question 2 should be no since otherwise how can we know which room the lady is in? Since we know that the sign on 1st door must be false since if it's true, the 2nd sign is automatically true. Therefore if the 2nd sign is false, that means the lady is either not in room 1 or the tiger is not in room 2. That gives us 3 options: both lady & tiger are in room 1; both lady and tiger are in room 2, or lady is in room 2 and tiger in room 1. I feel this question would have a definite answer if and only if the rule of not having both in same room is put into place.

@BobMarley If both the lady and the tiger are in the same room, does that mean that the tiger or the lady are not in one of the rooms? If I put a toy in drawer A, and a sock in drawer A, then both the toy and the sock will still be in one of the drawers, no?

I'm not following.

@BobMarley The answer for question 2 should be yes. So the question must have a definitive answer: No way around it. The reason? The Q reads: "In one of these rooms, there's a lady, and in one of them there is a tiger". So technically if both the lady and the tiger are in the same room, then it still holds true that both the tiger and the lady are in a room. It might be the same room, but it is a room nonetheless.

@BobMarley Therefore, when sign two is true, then sign one can be false. Just put both the tiger and the lady in the same room. However, if sign two is false, then sign one must also be false.

3 options: both lady & tiger are in room 1; both lady and tiger are in room 2, or lady is in room 2 and tiger in room. How do we know if lady is in room 1 or 2?

@BobMarley The question isn't asking for you to determine the instance where in every case, one sign must be false and the other must be true. It's asking does there exist an option where one sign must be true and the other must be false. It will never be true that sign two is false and sign one is true. However, there can be a case where sign one is false and sign two is true.

@BobMarley Okay, I just re-read the initial question: The answer should be that the lady can be in either room. Sorry, I forgot that part.

"Behind which door is the lady?" (quoted from question) They're asking where is the lady. I'm not understanding how your answer tells me where the lady is supposed to be located?

@BobMarley (comment may have slipped by.) Did you see my newest comment? I realized that the question wasn't asking explicitly for which sign must be true, and which must be false. Rather, it's asking for which door the lady is behind. So your conclusion on the three cases is correct, and therefore the lady can be behind either door.

Yup just saw you're answer. K cool will do.
